# Value of attribute is not getting passed to a variable in other script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript at my server end. In that script after some functions are run i am getting a value which is particularly path of websocket.I am setting that path as an attribute of javascript object.That javascript object is a chat popup whose html exists on my website.

**myscript.js**

```
//----------some_exisiting_code-----------
  var ws_path  = "ws://some-ip-address/chat/id/"  //This path is just an example.The path will be calculated dynamically by above existing lines of code.
  $(".chat-popup").attr("path",ws_path);
//----------some_exisiting_code-----------
```

**mypage.html**

```
//Importing myscript.js from server
  <script src="http://my-server-address/static/myscript.js"></script>

// passing value of "path" attribute as websocket endpoint
  <script> 
    var endpoint = $(".chat-popup").attr("path");
    var socket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(endpoint);
  </script>

  <div class="chat-popup">
   <div class="chat-history">   
    <ul id='chat-items'></ul>  
   </div>

   <div class="message">

 <!------------Message to be sent----------------------->
   <form id='form' method='POST'> 
     <input type="hidden" name="">
     <input id="id_message" type="text">        
     <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'/>
  </form>   
<!------------------------------------------------------------------>
</div></div>
```

I am getting **error:endpoint is undefined**.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: You forgot a starting double-quote

Comment: That's a typo sir. I have edited it. Thanks for getting through my code@KrishnaPrashatt

Comment: it's enough to wrap everything in [document-ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your "myscript.js" file in the footer of the page. and you can also add "jquery.min.js" file.

**myscript.js**

```
//----------some_exisiting_code-----------
var ws_path  = "ws://some-ip-address/chat/id/"  //This path is just an example.The path will be calculated dynamically by above existing lines of code.
//alert(ws_path);

$(".chat-popup").attr("path",ws_path);
//----------some_exisiting_code-----------
```

**mypage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="chat-popup">
       <div class="chat-history">   
        <ul id='chat-items'></ul>  
       </div>

       <div class="message">

        <!------------Message to be sent----------------------->
           <form id='form' method='POST'> 
             <input type="hidden" name="">
             <input id="id_message" type="text">        
             <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'/>
          </form>   
        <!------------------------------------------------------------------>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
<script> 
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var endpoint = $(".chat-popup").attr("path");
        alert(endpoint);
        var  socket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(endpoint);
    });
</script>
```